# What are the criteria for questions to appear in the list for choosing to use on tour page?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, tour

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/about/choose-question

On this page there is a list of questions, from which moderators can choose one question to be shown on the /tour page.

> [image]

What are the criteria for questions to appear in the list?

Comment: The answer there is in a link to an SEDE query. I've posted another answer to that question to provide a plain-English summary of that query.